# Mysql Temporary Table Syntax

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I have a question about the syntax for creating and accessing temporary tables.
Here is a 
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288908/joining-the-result-of-two-queries-mysql).

#### My table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `table1`
--

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `name`, `address`) VALUES
(1, 'andrew', '5 road'),
(2, 'bob', '6 street');
```

I am running this query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable SELECT id, name, address
FROM table1
SELECT id, name, address
FROM temptable
```

And tried this one

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable SELECT id, name, address
FROM table1
DESCRIBE temptable
```

Creating the temp table works, but then when I try to get info out of the temp table I get a message saying I need to check my sql syntax.
thanks
andrew

Comment: how are you trying to get info? describe works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left out the ';' after each statement. My query should have looked like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable SELECT id, name, address
FROM table1;
SELECT id, name, address
FROM temptable;
```

Details are important in programming and so is stackoverflow

Comment: :))) ... yes, i was copy pasting from your question, but I used ;

Comment: It's always the little things, I spend hours trying to learn about temp tables and then realise I just left some semi-colons out. haha